# Git: Remove everything except for a certain directory (BFG Repo Cleaner)

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am trying to permanently remove all traces of all directories in a Git repository *except* for one directory, say named *keep-me*.

For such tasks, the BFG repo cleaner is my usual go-to tool. However, it does not seem to support this operation (in fact, I believe it does not support extended globs). I am really trying to accomplish the following, which does not get rid of the other directories:

```
java -jar ~/bfg-1.12.12.jar --delete-folders {!(keep-me)} my-repo.git
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to keep track of changes in these dirs? If not you can just add them in your .gitignore file.

Comment: No, that's not an appropriate solution at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it the other way round:

```
git subtree split --prefix keep-me --branch cleaned-branch
```

This will create a new project history in the branch `cleaned-branch` which only contains `keep-me`.

Comment: Thanks, Lars, this worked. Here is a great blog post on how to split two repositories (which I should have followed from the start): https://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/